# Facebook Get Friends Batch

Tags: javascript, facebook, api

I want to get facebook friends in batch

```
$['getJSON']('https://graph.facebook.com/' + m + '/friends?access_token=xxxxx
```

By this Code Im Getting All friends

I want first 30 friends then Next 30 friends

Is There any way I can get that ?

Comment: Use paging of the fb api

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=facebook+api+paging -> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/pagination/ ... _Some_ own research effort, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add `&limit=30` to the end of your Graph API call, you can achieve paging. The response will also give you links to access the next and previous 30 friends.